¿Por qué cuando ingreso un número de 4 cifras que comienza con 0 lo toma como si fuera de 3 cifras?
Estoy haciendo un juego de picas y fijas que toma un número de 4 cifras ingresado por el jugador y lo guarda en un vector que será comparado con el número generado al azar. Todo funciona bien excepto cuando el número ingresado por el jugador empieza por 0 ya que lo da como inválido porque lo ve como si fuera de 3 cifras
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>



int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
std::vector <short int> num = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
};

short int n_azar;
std::vector <short int> num_incogn = {}; //el vector que va a contener el número que hay que adivinar
int numero;
bool num_correcto = false;
int intento; //este es el número ingresado por el usuario en cada intento
std::vector <short int> vector_reves = {};
std::vector <short int> vector_intento = {};
short int picas;
short int fijas;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   n_azar = rand() %10;
   numero = num[n_azar];
   if(std::find(num_incogn.begin(), num_incogn.end(), numero) !=num_incogn.end() == false && num_incogn.size()<4){
       num_incogn.push_back(numero); //genera un número al azar de cuatro cifras y evita que haya alguna cifra repetida
    } 
}


std::cout << '\n' << "Ingrese un número de 4 cifras:" << std::endl;

while(num_correcto == false){
    std::cin >> intento;
    while(intento > 0 && intento < 10000 && vector_reves.size()<4){
      

a continuación se convierte el número ingresado por el usuario en un vector de 4 elementos, con el inconveniente de que los pone en reversa
vector_reves.push_back(intento % 10);
        intento/=10;
    } 
    
    if(vector_reves.size()<4 || vector_reves.size()>4){ //esto verifica que el número no tenga ni más ni menos de 4 cifras
        std::cout << "El número debe ser de 4 cifras" << std::endl;
        break;
         
    }
    
   if(vector_intento.size() < 4 ){

luego toma los elementos del vector que está al reves y los guarda en el vector_intento en el orden correcto
vector_intento.insert(vector_intento.end(), vector_reves.rbegin(), vector_reves.rend());
   }
   
   for(int x : vector_intento){
       std::cout << x ;
   }
   
   for (size_t i = 0; i < vector_intento.size(); i++){
       if(vector_intento[i] == num_incogn[i]){
           fijas++;
       }
       else if(std::find(num_incogn.begin(), num_incogn.end(), vector_intento[i]) !=num_incogn.end()){
           picas++;
       }
   }
   
   
    std::cout << " ";   
    if(fijas >0){
        std::cout << fijas << "f" << " ";
    }
    if(picas >0){
        std::cout << picas << "p";
    }
    
    if (fijas == 4){
        std::cout << '\n' << "¡Victoria!";
        num_correcto = true;
        
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    //lo siguiente deja todo en 0 para continuar con el siguiente intento
    vector_reves = {};
    vector_intento = {};
    picas = 0;
    fijas = 0;
}    

return 0;}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si es un numero, no puede empezar con un cero... los numeros no empiezan en cero... hay un problema en tu logica, que tengas que adivinar numeros, no quiere decir que tengas que usar un int para guardar lo que se ingresa.. deberias guardar una cadena de 4 posiciones y validar que los 4 sean numeros ;)

Porque efectivamente, una secuencia de cuatro números cuyo primer número es un cero, es un número de tres cifras.

"0000" es cero (0).
"0003" es tres (3).
"0023" es veintitrés (23).
"0123" es ciento veintitrés (123).

Si quieres tratar los números como cadenas no leas un número, lee una cadena.
Si además de comprobar que has leído cuatro caracteres, quieres comprobar que todos ellos sean un número, puedes leer el texto sobre una variable numérica y si no falla es que es un número:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Ingrese un n de 4 cifras:\n";

    std::string numero;
    std::cin >> numero;

    if (numero.length() != 4ul)
        std::cout << numero << " no es de cuatro cifras.\n";

    int valor;
    if (std::stringstream ss(numero); !(ss >> valor))
        std::cout << numero << " no es un numero.\n";

    return 0;
}

Puedes ver el código anterior funcionando en Try it online!.

La función std::cin asume que el número ingresado no comenzará con un cero, y cuando se ingresa la secuencia de números 0123, lo que la función interpreta es que los últimos tres dígitos 123 serán considerados y se ignorará el cero inicial.
En C++, el cero al principio no tiene longitud y no se considera como un entero. Tampoco almacena el cero a la izquierda; al leer el número, std::cin lo almacena como int, y cualquier cero a la izquierda es descartado.
Es necesario mantenerlo como una cadena de caracteres ( string ).
